# How should I tell a period between two dates?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-choice

How should I tell a period between two dates? For example,

1. The DVD contains data **from** April 2010 **to** July 2019.
2. The DVD contains data **from** April 2010 **until** July 2019.
3. The DVD contains data **between** April 2010 **and** July 2019.

Which one is correct or better?

Comment: Grammatically, prefer **from** one point **to** another. But for clarity, you would need to add a date to show whether both months were inclusive. **From April 1 to July 31** or similar.

Comment: @RonaldSole For further clarity they should specify whether July 31 is included: "from ... to 11:59 PM on July 31"... but then is the minute at 11:59 included? Ad infinitum, ad nauseum... we can be as specific or as vague as we like :)